# Possible to test a cast to PropertyInfo.PropertyType when object implements implicit operator?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, operator-keyword, propertyinfo

I have an object of a certain type (`SpecialImage`) which implements an *implicit operator* to another type (`Image`).

`SpecialImage` does **not** derive from `Image`. However the following is possible through the operator:

```
var someImage = new Image();
(SpecialImage)someImage;
```

I have an object with properties which I'm looping through by reflection and an `Image` object:

**Is it possible to check if the object is castable to `info.PropertyType` before trying to set the value?**

```
var someImage = new Image();

foreach(PropertyInfo info in someOjbect.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    //info.PropertyType == typeof(SomeImage);

    //Is it possible to check if the object is castable to 
    //info.PropertyType before trying to set the value?
    info.SetValue(someObject, someImage, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

If we have these classes

```
class T1
{
}

class T2
{
    public static implicit operator T1(T2 item) { return new T1(); }
}
```

The we could use

```
if(typeof(T2).GetMethods().Where (
    t => t.IsStatic && t.IsSpecialName && 
         t.ReturnType == typeof(T1) && t.Name=="op_Implicit").Any())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I found this and indeed this works. Is there no nicer way __without__ having to change the class and for instance convert IConvertible?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You could wrap that code in a helper method to tidy it away.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075471/implicit-version-of-isassignablefrom and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224266/how-to-tell-if-type-a-is-implicitly-convertible-to-type-b for more info.