# Know if variable of type A can be casted to type B

Tags: c#, casting

I know that I can cast (implicitly) a `int` to a `float`, or a `float` to a `double`.
Also, I can cast (explicitly) a `double` to a `float`, or to an `int`.

This can be proved by the following example:

```
int i;
float f;

// The smaller type fits into the bigger one
f = i;

// And the bigger type can be cut (losing precision) into a smaller
i = (int)f;
```

The problem is that this types aren't inherited one from another (`int` isn't a subtype of `float` or vice-versa).
They have implemented a *implicit/explicit casting operator* or something like that. If not, it works like it is...

My question is: How can I check if **a variable of type A can be casted to type B**.

I've tried `i.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(f.GetType())`, but `Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)` only checks inheritance and interfaces (and maybe something more), but doesn't check the implemented casting operator.
I've tried `i is float` and `f is int`, but the effect is the same.

Comment: You can use reflection to see if types have implicit cast operators. Than read C# specification and see how implicit conversion rules are applied...

Comment: You need to use reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075471/implicit-version-of-isassignablefrom

Answer (score 1):

For implicit types (`int`, `float`, etc) you can use a `TypeConverter` to determine if a variable of type *a* can be converted to type *b*. You can find a reference to the appropriate type converter by using one of the overloads of [`TypeDescriptor.GetConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter.aspx) (System.ComponentModel).

For custom or other reference types, I would recommend [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) (as referenced in the question). The proper use of such method would be:

```
var implType = typeof(List<>);
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(implType))
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is convertible to '{1}'", implType, typeof(IEnumerable));
```

The above example will tell you whether the type `List<T>` is convertible to `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
//Type a and b stuff defined 
a c = null;
try
{
   c = (a)b;
}
catch{}
if(c==null)
   //Do stuff
```

Comment: Yikes. Is that an empty catch?

Comment: @ismellike It suppresses `all` errors, except of the one you're looking for. Also you should add meaningful error handling, or `at least` a comment indicating what you want.